# Issue with vertical and horizontal scroll in Xamarin Forms (Android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin. I am trying to create a sample in Xamarin forms with 5 custom horizontallistviews (I have used renderers to achieve the same in different platforms. It works perfectly (scrolls horizontally) when I have only 2 of these controls on screen. When I add all the 5 I have to add these controls inside a ScrollView oriented vertically so that I can see all the controls. When I do that I am only able to scroll the page vertically. I am not able to scroll the individual controls (horizontallistviews) horizontally.

This issue is only with Android. It works fine in Windows Phone.

Below is my code:

```
    <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
       <StackLayout Padding="5, 25" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Image Source ="label_entertainment.png" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
          <local:HorizontalListViewEntertainment x:Name="entertainmentView" Items="{Binding Entertainment}" HeightRequest="198"/>
          <Image Source ="label_music.png" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
          <local:HorizontalListViewMusic x:Name="musicListView" Items="{Binding Music}" HeightRequest="198"/>
          <Image Source ="label_movies.png" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
          <local:HorizontalListViewMovies x:Name="movieListView" Items="{Binding Movies}" HeightRequest="198"/>
          <Image Source ="label_celebrities.png" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
          <local:HorizontalListViewCelebrities x:Name="celebritiesListView" Items="{Binding Celebrities}" HeightRequest="198"/>
          <Image Source ="label_style.png" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
          <local:HorizontalListViewStyle x:Name="styleListView" Items="{Binding Celebrities}" HeightRequest="198"/>
      </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

I found a solution [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20834/horizontal-scrollview-within-vertical-scrollview). However it doesn't work in my case because I don't have inner scroll views. Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. I just had to add the following code to the CustomRenderer of the horizontallistviews in android.

```
public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                StartX = e.RawX;
                StartY = e.RawY;
                this.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                if (IsHorizontal * Math.Abs(StartX - e.RawX) < IsHorizontal * Math.Abs(StartY - e.RawY))
                    this.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                this.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
        }
        return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
    }
```

Referred [this](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20834/horizontal-scrollview-within-vertical-scrollview)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using both ScrollViewand HorizontalScrollView ? http://android-code-crumbs.blogspot.ro/2011/06/how-to-set-horizontal-and-vertical.html